# How to add contextual menu items to the ellipsis menu in a Gmail Add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm building a Gmail add-on using Google Apps Script.

How can I change the universal menu items contextually as shown in the Evernote add-on example below? As far as I know, these menu items are set in the manifest, and I can't find a way to change them.

[image: evernote add-on screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is called a [`CardAction`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action). They are not menu items *per se*, but effectively function as such, forming the ellipsis menu together with [universal actions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/universal-actions) defined in the manifest.

Note (see the [official guide](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/actions)) that `CardAction`s differ from [`Actions`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action) as the former add nothing to the `Card` UI, placing the actions under the ellipsis menu:

> Note: Don't confuse Action objects with CardAction objects. CardAction objects are **card header menu items**, while Action objects define responses to user interactions with the UI.

Currently, there are several action types that `CardActions` can initiate:

1. Start an authorization flow ([`setAuthorizationAction`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action#setauthorizationactionaction))
2. Create a draft message ([`setComposeAction`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action#setComposeAction(Action,ComposedEmailType)))
3. Execute a function on click ([`setOnClickAction`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action#setOnClickAction(Action)))
4. Open a specified link ([`setOnClickOpenLinkAction`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action#setOnClickOpenLinkAction(Action))), optionally producing side-effects
5. Open a link using a fullscreen or popup dialog ([`setOpenLink`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action#setopenlinkopenlink))

---

You can create a menu builder utility for a [`Card`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card) that will look something like this (the sample is in TypeScript):

```js
declare interface ActionOptions {
  text: string;
  action: GoogleAppsScript.Card_Service.Action;
}

const buildMenu = (
  builder: GoogleAppsScript.Card_Service.CardBuilder,
  items: ActionOptions[] = []
) => {
  items.forEach(({ text, action }) => {
    const ca = CardService.newCardAction();
    ca.setText(text);
    
    //assign a specific action type, i.e.:
    //ca.setOnClickAction(action);

    builder.addCardAction(ca);
  });

  //if used as pass-through, return the builder
  return builder.build();
};
```

Comment: I'm asking about how to deliver different items when the top menu is open. The left screen shows 2 items while the right shows 4.

Comment: Perhaps your sample seems relating to how to arrange components within the card, rather than in the top menu.

Comment: @ddffbb - that's exactly what the sample is about (adding menu items). Despite what naming of the `CardAction` might make you think, the items added are put under the ellipsis menu (they do not appear anywhere on the card), and this is the only way you get the conditional menu items. The `Refresh` and `Manage add-on` items are added by default since the switch to the V8 runtime ( before the change, I had to make my own "refresh" items )